Cascaded loop: measured variables required
Could anyone help me with the following question:
"A two-loop, cascaded control is considered, the inner loop corresponds to a standard control loop with the transfer functions Gi(s) and Ri(s) and the disturbance z(t). The inner loop is enclosed by the outer loop with the transfer functions Ga(s) and Ra(s). The outer loop has no interference. The inner loop is now supplemented by an ideal disturbance feedforward FA(s).
How many measured variables does the feedback law require in total?"

Since this looks like a homework question, please [edit] into the question, your attempts at solving it and tell us exactly where you are stuck. Please visit the [tour] page if you have not already done so, to know how to improve the chances of getting an answer.
